# Serialize select option fields

Tags: jquery, serialization

I need to serialize all fields in a form except `select option` tags where the value selected is the default value. My select option html tag is like so. If the selected option has no value it needs to be ignored from the jquery serialize method.

```
<select>
  <option>Select a brand</option>
  <option value='1'>Sony</option>
  <option value='2'>Apple</option>
  <option value='3'>Nokia</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the answers but I was able to achieve it via this code `$(':not(select[value=""])', myForm).serialize()`;

Comment: i am not able figure out how did you do it can you make a fiddle to let me know how you dis it  or update this fidlle --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/JENyF/1

Comment: here is the example--> http://jsfiddle.net/crazyMAN/w3Mjn/ . select a brand or keep its default value & click the serialize button the text box below will display the serialized value.

Comment: thumbs you made it work and i took the question other way around lol

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/JENyF/1)

```
function showValues() {
    var str = $('#form1').clone();
    $.each(str[0], function (i, val) {
        var str_new = '<pre>' + str[0][i] + '</pre>';
        if (str_new === '<pre>[object HTMLSelectElement]</pre>') {
            str[0][i].disabled = 'true';
        }
    });
    var str_serialize = str.serialize();
    $('#test').text(str_serialize);
    console.log(str_serialize);
}
$('#sbt').click(function () {
    showValues();
});
```

new `var str` clone of the `form` with id `form1`

used `$.each()` to loop around the array of clone variable

using `'<pre>' + str[0][i] + '</pre>'` these tags it returns like for select tag `<pre>[object HTMLSelectElement]</pre>` object type

if `<pre>[object HTMLSelectElement]</pre>` is matched then i `disabled` it in the clone

in the end i used `serialize()` to the clone and it worked.